# How can you get the post category on single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, fishpig

How can you get the post category on single.php?

I've tried:

```
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->get_the_category()) ?></h1>
```

&

```
   <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->get_category_parents( $cat, true, ' &raquo; ' )) ?>
```

&

```
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->get_the_category($post->ID)) ?></h1>
```

This is the entire file:

```
<?php $post = $this->getPost() ?>
<?php if ($post): ?>
    <?php $helper = $this->helper('wordpress') ?>
    <?php $author = $post->getAuthor() ?>


    <div class="page-title post-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->get_the_category($post->ID)) ?></h1>
        <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-view">
        <p class="post-date when"><?php echo stripslashes($this->__('<span class=\"by-author\"> by %s</span> on %s.', $post->getAuthor()->getDisplayName(), $post->getPostDate())) ?></p>
        <?php echo $this->getBeforePostContentHtml() ?>
        <div class="post-entry entry std<?php if ($post->getFeaturedImage()): ?> post-entry-with-image<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php if ($post->isViewableForVisitor()): ?>
<!--                --><?php //if ($featuredImage = $post->getFeaturedImage()): ?>
<!--                    <div class="featured-image left"><img src="--><?php //echo $featuredImage->getAvailableImage() ?><!--" alt="--><?php //echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?><!--"/></div>-->
<!--                --><?php //endif; ?>
                <?php echo $post->getPostContent() ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPasswordProtectHtml() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getAfterPostContentHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getCommentsHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm working on WordPress through the Fishpig WordPress integration for Magento so the file path is template/wordpress/post/view.phtml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomas is correct; you cannot use WordPress code in a Magento template file, even if that template file is integrating WordPress. None of the WP library code is included so the WP functions that you include do not exist.

It is still possible to get all of the WP data you require via Magento code though. To get a posts categories, use the following code:

```
<?php $categories = $post->getParentCategories() ?>
<?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try write without `$post` like.

```
get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
```

instead of `$post->get_the_category($post->ID)`

Comment: that throws back an error _CALL TO UNDEFINED FUNCTION GET_THE_CATEGORY()_

Comment: which is your wordpress version.

Comment: I think it's related to this `I'm working on WordPress through the Fishpig WordPress integration for Magento so the file path is template/wordpress/post/view.phtml.` As the get_the_category function is for use inside The Loop, and it's in Wordpress since version 0.71, so, he can't be using a Wordpress that old.

Comment: @renishkhunt - you have answered for pure wordpress site and this question belongs to wordpress + Magento which is bridge via Fishpig module.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getPages() {
    $pages = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/page_collection')
        ->addIsViewableFilter()
        ->orderByMenuOrder()
        ->setOrderByPostDate()
        ->load();
    return $pages;
}

$pages = getPages();

foreach ($pages as $post):
    Collection goes here
endforeach;
```

Comment: Please, take a time to explain your answer, don't just post code

Comment: I think you are unsure about the question what is asked over here!